# How many seconds have passed in Mainframe?

Tags: reboot-1994

In the television show *ReBoot*, time is treated differently, with cycles and seconds being the units of time and a second is more like a year in our terms.

My question is, since the start of the show, how many seconds have passed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Impossible to say, because the show contradicts itself.

Most of the show's [references to the physical world's time units](https://reboot.wikia.com/wiki/Nanosecond) suggest that characters in Mainframe experience existence more rapidly than people in the physical world.

This is at odds with Enzo Matrix's aging in season 3, and in particular with Turbo's statement in ["The Episode With No Name"](https://reboot.wikia.com/wiki/The_Episode_With_No_Name) (season 3, episode 8; 1997) that time inside game cubes runs faster than ordinary system time.  Since the User avatar in a game must be able to interact with the game world at a rate that the User in the physical world can comprehend, game time must correspond approximately to physical time.  Ordinary system time, at least as far the characters in Mainframe experience it, must therefore run slower than physical time.